# JSON dont return assignments that is related to a person (Visual studio 2012, MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Hi im trying to return JSON with a person and the skills that are related to this person.

I have a class person

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int personID { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }

}
```

And a class Skill

```
public class Skill
{
    [Key]
    public int skillID { get; set; }
    public int personID { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

DB context

```
    public class ConsultantContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Skill> Skill { get; set; }

}
```

And i fill upp with some data.

public class PersonInit : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges
    {
        protected override void Seed(ConsultantContext context)
        {

```
        var skills = new List<Skill>
        {

            new Skill { skillID = 1, personID = 1, title = "Javascript" },
            new Skill { skillID = 2, personID = 1, title = "jQuery" },
            new Skill { skillID = 3, personID = 1, title = "ASP.NET" }
        };
        skills.ForEach(s => context.Skills.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();


        var persons = new List<Person>
        {

            new Person { personID = 1, firstName = "Name1",   lastName = "Lastname1", age = 30, role = "Programmer" },
            new Person { personID = 2, firstName = "Name2",   lastName = "Lastname2", age = 30, role = "Designer" },
            new Person { personID = 3, firstName = "Name3",   lastName = "Lastname3", age = 30, role = "Manager" }
        };
        persons.ForEach(s => context.Persons.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();




    }

}
```

I have a controller called Person

```
  public class PersonController : ApiController
{
    private ConsultantContext db = new ConsultantContext();

    // GET api/Person
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        return db.Persons.AsEnumerable();
    }

    // GET api/Person/5
    public Person GetPerson(int id)
    {
        Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
        if (person == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return person;
    }

    // PUT api/Person/5
    public HttpResponseMessage PutPerson(int id, Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && id == person.personID)
        {
            db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }

    // POST api/Person
    public HttpResponseMessage PostPerson(Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Persons.Add(person);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, person);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = person.personID }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }

    // DELETE api/Person/5
    public HttpResponseMessage DeletePerson(int id)
    {
        Person person = db.Persons.Find(id);
        if (person == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        db.Persons.Remove(person);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, person);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

So now to the problem when i use the http:/localhost/api/Person in fiddler it returns JSON:

it returns an empty [].

Can someone help me get JSON back with the personID, name, lastname, role and skills[belonging to this person].

Regards

Comment: can you supply the code for the API itself?

Comment: Are you trying to do MVC or WCF?

Comment: http:/localhost/api/Person without a value after Person is doing a post with the values of your text fields being passed as a person object

Comment: MVC, if i remove the Skills it returns JSON with Persons, i want to add skills to the persons and return json so i can map with jquery mapping into javascript knockouts.

Comment: Im only doing GET. Dont look at the post

Comment: You're saying you are using MVC, but the title and tags indicate Web API. These are different products. From the code, it appears to be Web API, in which case people coming in later should be aware you are using Web API and not MVC.

Comment: Why are you directly returning the person entity and not a viewmodel or dto?  If you went that route you could avoid any issues with EF.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        var skills = db.Skill;
        var people = db.Persons;
        people.ForEach(person => person.Skills = skills.FindAll(skill => skill.personID == person.personID));

        return people;
    }
```

Comment: If you look at this article im not supposed to do that? http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: I apologize @rubin, I thought you were attempting WCF, so ignore the Data stuff :)

Comment: My fault, should had written ASP.NET MVC =) It works and returns JSON with only the persons, but i want to add all the skills and return json so i can map it with jQuery mapping into javascript knockouts so i need it to be  JSON name, skills[skill1, skill2, skill3] etc

Comment: I edited my answer, I don't know if it will exactly work since I did it from the top of my head, but you should get the idea I'm going for

Comment: Basically what I'm doing is loading each of the contexts, then iterating through each person and assigning the skills to them that way. I didn't see you loading the skills before

Comment: I thought it was easier than that, if i have a public virtual ICollection in Person and a public virtual Person Person in Skill that the controller would get that they belong to each other when they have the same personID

Comment: the virtual attribute gives it a lazy load, meaning it doesn't load it until it's needed, and since you don't define that it's needed, you have to load it explicitly